# Есть ли аналог Cheerio на клиенте?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, парсер, dom

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли библиотека подобная Cheerio только что бы работала на клиенте?

Comment: что это за библиотека? какой именно функционал ты хочешь?

Comment: [implementation of core jQuery](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) - бери [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)

Comment: Если в курсе что такое Cheerio то нужно то же самое только на стороне клиента. Если вкратце - делаем аякс запрос на с сайта  Х на сайт У получаем html в виде простого текста и теперь надо из этого текста вытянуть необходимую информацию.

Comment: Не в курсе, но если это библиотека, ссылку на которую я кинул в предыдущем комментарии, то в ее описании написано, что это имплементация jQuery